# Could “Instead,” be used as the first word of a sentence without any following “of”?

Tags: word-usage

Would the following sentence be correct? If not, I am looking for an adverb to express the meaning of “instead”.

> Our team could have won the match if our coach had interchanged the goal keeper after the collision. **Instead,** our coach decided to interchange an attacker, which proved to be a bad team management decision.

Can “Instead” and comma be used to begin a sentence, without any following “of”?

Comment: Yes, it can. The sentence is grammatical and meaningful.

Comment: The quote is a perfectly normal use of "Instead,".  It is similar to "However," in this sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could certainly use an adverb like *unfortunately* to emphasize that the decision was a poor one.  But simply using *instead* with the comma is grammatically correct.